# Call function on export event of reportviewer in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, rdlc, reportviewer

I am using `RDLC` report and it is showing that report in report viewer using asp.net. I have to update some flags in the database after the user exports the report in PDF or whatever. So, is there any event that fires on report viewer export button? I tried to find this event or a solution but can't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the [ReportViewer.ReportExport Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.winforms.reportviewer.reportexport.aspx). I haven't tried it myself but you should be able to something like this:

```
reportViewer.ReportExport += new ExportEventHandler(sender, args);
```

... and then add your code in the following handler:

```
public void ExportEventHandler(object sender, ReportExportEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Extension.LocalizedName == "Adobe PDF")
    {
        // add your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time but this code is not working i think i am working on web application and `ReportViewer.ReportExport` Event only available in windows.